# Latest advice on the euro symbol

Tags: fonts, symbols

I know there are many packages that offer the euro symbol (€). But which is the best implementation? I read something a couple of years ago [which I can't now find] that assessed the option. But even if I could find it, I imagine things might have changed since it was written. So: which package provides the best euro symbol (in terms of accuracy to the [official specifications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aEuro_Construction.svg), in terms of looking good with the surrounding font and so on.) In response to Thorsten Donig's answer I should point out that these two desiderata seem in pretty much direct conflict if you're using a serif font.

The unicode symbol € doesn't work. (If you have a "compose key" it's "c=")

Comment: I would very much question the need to follow the Official Specification, unless you are in the business of printing money. Use what goes well with your fonts. As per the officials the euro symbol was based on the Greek epsilon and the two parallel lines are supposed to certify the *stability* of the new euro. Given the current crisis of the euro and especially in Greece, I wouldn't give a penny's thought of not using the "standard euro"! These gentlemen also had  other bright ideas - so that a modern Pericles is spelled "officially" as Periklis rather than the ancient Pericles!

Comment: @Yiannis the official specification was just an example of one criterion on which implementations of the euro symbol could be judged. How is "Pericles" ancient? Greek doesn't really have a "c"...

Comment: If you have trouble copying the euro sign from a latex-generated pdf, e.g. copying "100 €" results in "100 e" or "100 =C" or "100 ⁄", check out this answer, it worked for me (the font in the LaTeX template I need to use didn't support the € character, which results in the `Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.` warning) https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110979/178758

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The unicode symbol € does work, if you use a modern font that contains that symbol. :-)

The best practice is to use right symbol for right font. For Computer Modern fonts, `eurosym` is OK, or `textcomp` (using fonts provided by CM-super). See this FAQ for more packages:

https://texfaq.org/FAQ-euro

I suggest Latin Modern fonts (using `lmodern` together with `textcomp` package), which is similar to Computer Modern. So you can use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern,textcomp}
\begin{document}
€100
\end{document}
```

There are still some other font packages with euro symbol. If you use such font themes, use the euro symbol provided by the font package. For example, `libertine`, `fourier` and `mathdesign` package. Thus you can also use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{libertine} % or \usepackage{fourier} or \usepackage[utopia]{mathdesign}
\begin{document}
€100 % or \texteuro100
\end{document}
```

Using XeLaTeX, most modern OpenType/TrueType fonts have euro symbols, including default Latin Modern fonts. You can use them directly:

```
% xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}% Latin Modern by default
% or \setmainfont{Whatever you want}
\begin{document}
€100
\end{document}
```

Comment: What's the difference between utf8 and utf8x for inputenc?

Comment: @Seamus: `utf8x` option defines more symbols than `utf8` option, while it may cause more compatible problems.

Comment: I've just tried that and with Libertine, it does work. However, it fails for many other fonts that do have an Euro glyph (e.g. OpenSans, via `\usepackage[default]{opensans}`). Why oh why?

Comment: @Seamus I've been told that the `utf8x` option ought not be used. (By egreg among others.) *Even* when `utf8` lacks necessary characters.

Comment: Nice answer. Note that this did not work for me in math mode (did not investigate further, I just put the euro symbol into text mode for a quick fix).

Answer (score 35):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{eurosym}

\begin{document}

10€ and 10\euro

\let\texteuro\euro
10€ and 10\euro

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The package `textcomp` is not needed. If you are using `utf8` and `eurosym` you can just declare: `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{20AC}{\euro}` as mentioned in the [manual](http://www.theiling.de/eurosym.html.en).

Answer (score 22):

The [eurosym](http://ctan.org/pkg/eurosym) package is the one and only that translates the official specifications.

Comment: Ya but it's kind of _ugly_

Comment: But if you want to do it right, there is no alternative.

Comment: @ThorstenDonig: That really depends on what your gauge for "right" is. _If_ the designers of the official Euro symbol were intending for it to be used in all instances, regardless of the font used (which I'm not sure they did), I would probably decide not to let them tell me what's _right_, but rather conform to my own typographical opinion.

Comment: @doncherry: Designer of the official »Euro« currency symbol is the European Union. And this design does not depend on a font. The specifications of that symbol can be read in the package manual. The package authors simply made this official symbol available for LaTeX. It's up to you decide what form of Euro symbol you want to use. If you want the official version, this package is the way to go, or [MarVoSym](http://ctan.org/pkg/marvosym) as alternative. I think there is no room for a "typographical opinion" in this case.

Comment: IMO, `eurosym` beats `{lmodern,textcomp}` hands down. `eurosym` is a nice crisp n sharp symbol, whereas `{lmodern,textcomp}` produces sth reminiscent of a symbol hit by a truck.

Comment: eurosym is not working for me, I simply get the letter $e$. Should I start a new question?

Comment: There is also an euroitc package.