# textcomp makes \textbullet smaller when using helvet font

Tags: fonts, symbols, incompatibility, textcomp

I'm writing a document which requires the `helvet` font and, in order to [get access to the euro symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9866/latest-advice-on-the-euro-symbol), I am now trying to load the `textcomp` package.

However this package has the strange side effect of making the symbol produced by `\textbullet`, e.g. as used by an `itemize` environment, a bit smaller. I could live with that, but I sort of prefer the slightly larger bullet, so I'm wondering if there is an easy way to load `textcomp` but without changing the size of the bullet?

A small example showing the problem

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
% Uncomment the following line to see the problem 
%\usepackage{textcomp}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item One
\item Two
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, if you really want the origin `\textbullet`:

```
\DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\textbullet}{OMS}
```

---

Second, which is better? I know it is subjective, but I just want to explain what `textcomp` do.

With `textcomp` package, the text symbols are redeclared in new `TS1` encoding, instead of Knuth's `OMS` encoding (designed for origin CM fonts). It is suitable for 8 bits fonts (256 glyphs).

If you use `OMS` encoding for `\textbullet`, then `\textbullet` is the same as

```
{\usefont{OMS}{phv}{m}{n}\symbol{15}}
```

And check `omsphv.fd` you'll find

```
\DeclareFontShape{OMS}{phv}{m}{n}
   {<-> ssub * cmsy/m/n}{}
```

i.e. Computer Modern Symbol font (`cmsy`) is used. In fact, it is not very suitable for Adobe Helvetica font (`phv` family).

If `textcomp` is used, `\textbullet` is in `TS1` encoding, the result is the same as

```
{\usefont{TS1}{phv}{m}{n}\symbol{136}}
```

And check `ts1phv.fd` you'll find

```
\DeclareFontShape{TS1}{phv}{m}{n}{
   <-> \Hv@@scale phvr8c
}{}
```

That's real Helvetica. (Actully Nimbus Sans in most TeX distributions)

Comment: Just to let you know, I was sold by your argument that I should use the smaller bullet. Still, I am leaning to the euro symbol from `eurosymb`. I wish I could accept both answers, as learned a lot really from both!

Answer (score 6):

Don't use `textcomp` for the Euro symbol. There's `eurosym`, which provides the official symbol.

If you want to input the Euro symbol directly with the Unicode character and the `utf8` option to `inputenc`, you can write

```
\usepackage{eurosym,newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{€}{\officialeuro}
```

You won't be able to find `€` in the PDF, though. For that you need to add some magic:

```
\immediate\pdfobj stream {
  /CIDInit /ProcSet findresource begin
  12 dict begin
  begincmap
  /CIDSystemInfo
  << /Registry (TeX)
  /Ordering (Euro)
  /Supplement 0
  >> def
  /CMapName /TeX-Euro-0 def
  /CMapType 2 def
  1 begincodespacerange
  <00> <FF>
  endcodespacerange
  1 beginbfchar
  <65> <20AC>
  endbfchar
  endcmap
  CMapName currentdict /CMap defineresource pop
  end
  end
}
\begingroup
\edef\next#1#2{%
  \noexpand\fontseries{#1}\noexpand\fontshape{#2}\noexpand\selectfont
  \pdffontattr\font{/ToUnicode \the\pdflastobj\space 0 R}}
\fontencoding{U}\fontfamily{eurosym}%
\next{m}{n}\next{m}{sl}\next{m}{ol}
\next{bx}{n}\next{bx}{sl}\next{bx}{sl}
\endgroup
```

Basically this adds a CMAP resource and maps all `eurosym` fonts to it.

Comment: It depends. For CM fonts, `eurosym` may be better (since the Euro symbol in CM super is ugly); but for those fonts that have Euro symbol, it is better to use `textcomp` to get the glyph in the font.

Comment: Actually the euro symbol from `eurosym` does look rather nice. I probably should ask another question but, is it possible to make the symbol itself € work in my document if I'm using `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` ?

Comment: @Juan: You'd have seen my answer in [Latest advice on the euro symbol](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9866/latest-advice-on-the-euro-symbol). Use `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}` instead.

Comment: Hmm.. I did saw that.. but it didn't work.. I now seem to find that the `utf8x` option and `biblatex` are incompatible. Biblatex complains about an incompatible package `ucs`.

Comment: @Leo Liu The font chosen through **helvet** surely hasn't it.

Comment: @Juan Look at the edited message.

Comment: @Juan: For better Unicode support, I suggest XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. `utf8x` option of `inputenc` does has some compatible issues.

Comment: @egreg: `helvet` only switch `phv` family in NFSS. Origin `\textbullet` uses `OMS` encoding and actually use `cmsy` font. With `textcomp`, `TS1` encoding is default, `\textbullet` uses `phvr8c` font, the same as the main text.

Comment: I got it now, thanks both for the very useful and informative answers!

Comment: +1 for the Unicode/mapping magic, but I agree with @LeoLiu in that you should check if the official symbol matches the font you use.

Comment: @doncherry I really don't like Euro symbols "matching" the current font. It's ugly anyway, so I prefer the official one. :)