# How to include the € symbol?

Tags: symbols, packages, unicode

In my *.cls class file I loaded

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

(does the order of the two matter?)

and get the following **error message**: `Command \texteuro unavailable in encoding  T1.`

- Why can't I insert the EURO € symbol?
- Do I need to to load a special package, e.g. `eurosym`?
- Can I just type it plainly, or do I need to wrap it in TeX-code?

Comment: HEre are some tips on typesetting the euro symbol: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9866/latest-advice-on-the-euro-symbol (possible duplicate?)

Comment: thx! I was googling the error message (see my question) and it returned no entries on SX... I'll take a look at that € thread.

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty Make sure to also use the site’s search function. A simple [search for `euro symbol`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=euro+symbol) would’ve sufficed.

Comment: @doncherry it's not *where* I searched but for *what* I searched: I was after the **error message** (which now, thx to this duplicate, will be found).

Answer (score 6):

Some fonts do not have euro symbol.  To allow TeX to construct a fake one for this case, just add the line

```
  \usepackage{textcomp}
```

or, in a `.cls` file

```
  \RequirePackage{textcomp}
```