# eurosym seems to not be working

Tags: symbols

I just tried the `eurosym` package for the first time, and when I try `$\euro$`, I simply get `e`. I have tried looking on line, for instance http://www.theiling.de/eurosym.html and [on CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/eurosym).

Seems to suggest that I should not be getting simply the letter `e`. I could see perhaps the convention switching to being simply the letter `$e$`, but would expect

1. that to be mentioned in some site associated with `eurosym`; and
2. why bother using `eurosym` to simply write the letter `e`.

Comment: Nothing in the `eurosym` package documentation suggests that you should use math mode for producing the Euro symbol €.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There is no reason why in general one should write `$\euro$` for getting the Euro € symbol. Just `\euro` in text mode works.

It might be a problem in case you *need* to use the symbol in math mode. The package doesn't cope with this case and effectively `$\euro$` simply produces *e*.

A workaround is to modify the standard definition:

```
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{amstext} % for \text
\DeclareRobustCommand{\officialeuro}{%
  \ifmmode\expandafter\text\fi
  {\fontencoding{U}\fontfamily{eurosym}\selectfont e}}
```

Complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{amstext} % for \text
\DeclareRobustCommand{\officialeuro}{%
  \ifmmode\expandafter\text\fi
  {\fontencoding{U}\fontfamily{eurosym}\selectfont e}}

\begin{document}
\euro{} in text mode

$\euro$ in math mode
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

A completely different problem that is not addressed by the package and by your question is how to make the Euro symbol searchable in the PDF file.

This can be obtained by defining a proper mapping of the character in the font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifpdf,eurosym,amstext}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\officialeuro}{%
  \ifmmode\expandafter\text\fi
  {\fontencoding{U}\fontfamily{eurosym}\selectfont{}e}}

\makeatletter
\ifpdf\ifdefined\pdffontattr
  \immediate\pdfobj stream {
    /CIDInit /ProcSet findresource begin
    12 dict begin
    begincmap
    /CIDSystemInfo
    << /Registry (TeX)
    /Ordering (Euro)
    /Supplement 0
    >> def
    /CMapName /TeX-Euro-0 def
    /CMapType 2 def
    1 begincodespacerange
    <00> <FF>
    endcodespacerange
    1 beginbfchar
    <65> <20AC>
    endbfchar
    endcmap
    CMapName currentdict /CMap defineresource pop
    end
    end
  }
  {\edef\@tempa#1#2{%
     \noexpand\fontseries{#1}\noexpand\fontshape{#2}\noexpand\selectfont
     \pdffontattr\font{/ToUnicode \the\pdflastobj\space 0 R}}
   \fontencoding{U}\fontfamily{eurosym}%
   \@tempa{m}{n}\@tempa{m}{sl}\@tempa{m}{ol}
   \@tempa{bx}{n}\@tempa{bx}{sl}
  }
\fi\fi
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\euro{} in text mode

$\euro$ in math mode
\end{document}
```

[image]

The image is taken from my PDF viewer and shows that both appearances of € are properly recognized. Here is the first line copied from the PDF file and simply pasted:

> € in text mode

Comment: Really great! I didn't knew about the mapping to get the character recognition.

Comment: You are the hero of my day – thank you so much! P.S.: By adding `\usepackage{newunicodechar}` and `\newunicodechar{€}{\euro}`, the `\euro` is not required anymore, but just a regular € sign can be used in the text editor.

Comment: @MatthiasLuh I wrote `newunicodechar` a few years after this answer. :-)

Comment: @egreg Thank you!!! :)

Answer (score 10):

A little less work than @egreg's solution: just use `\text` when in math mode:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
Here's \euro{} in text.

Now in math, inline $\text{\euro}$ and displayed:
\begin{equation*}
\text{\euro}5 + \text{\euro}5 = \text{\euro}10.
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:** define a new macro to save a little typing:

```
\newcommand{\meuro}{\text{\euro}}
...
\begin{equation*}
\meuro 5 + \meuro 5 = \meuro 10.
\end{equation*}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will probably use this for now, but since I do want to start increasing my LaTeX "programming" skills, I will definitely be trying to find time to absorb @egreg's solution.

Comment: @BradyTrainor egreg's solution is definitely the way to go! It is really good (I think) -- not that Ethan Bolker's solution isn't good, but the other is _very_ good.

Answer (score 4):

If you use the `eurosym` package along with its command `\euro` you'll get the Euro symbol.

Try running this:

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{eurosym}

\begin{document}     
\noindent Sample with eurosym: \euro  \\
Sample with e: $e$

\end{document}
```

And you'll get this output:

[image]

As you can see, there is a big difference between `$e$` and `\euro`.

Writing `$\euro$` does not produce the euro sign, but rather just and 'e'.