# Searching for Euro symbol

Tags: symbols, copy-paste, dvips, ps2pdf, dvi-mode

I found [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg)'s answer to the question "[eurosym seems to not be working](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110979/15874)" some time ago and it works perfect if I compile using `pdflatex`, but if I compile using

```
latex
dvips
ps2pdf
```

the Euro symbol is not searchable in the PDF file. How do I make it searchable if I compile using the latter procedure?

**Update**

I'm wondering if anyone is trying to "make an up to date Type1 font version of `feymr10.pfb` with the correct glyph name (`/Euro`)" (quoting [Heiko Oberdiek](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967/heiko-oberdiek)'s last comment) at the moment?

Comment: Good question. I don't know at all. Maybe some trickery with `accsupp`

Comment: @egreg Maybe `:)` It is beyond my (La)TeX skills.

Comment: Unfortunately the documentation of `accsupp` says that the marks it uses are not recognized by Ghostscript.

Comment: @egreg That is a shame, but thank you for letting me know that it cannot be fixed. (If you make the comment into an answer, I'll accept it.)

Comment: Let's wait for Heiko

Comment: @egreg Unhappily ghostscript does not implement the necessary `pdfmark` operators. Thus `accsupp` will not help here with `dvips`/`ps2pdf`. Nevertheless I have added an example.

Comment: @egreg: Someone could make an up to date Type1 font version `feymr10.pfb` with the correct glyph name (`/Euro`) ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As requested, an example using package `accsupp` that works for `pdfTeX`, the `dvipdfm` family (`dvipdfm`, `dvipdfmx`, `XeTeX`). In principle it could work for `dvips`, but from the documentation of `accsupp`:

> 1.3.3 Option dvips
>
> Package option dvips and its alias dvipsone write pdfmark specials in the output. Unhappily these pdfmark operators are ignored by ghostscript (latest tested version is 8.54). Perhaps they are recognized by commercial distiller applications.

Nevertheless, the example file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{amstext} % for \text
\usepackage{accsupp} % for PDF's ActualText feature

\DeclareRobustCommand{\officialeuro}{%
  \BeginAccSupp{%
    method=hex,
    unicode,
    ActualText=20AC,
  }%
    \ifmmode\expandafter\text\fi
    {%
      \fontencoding{U}\fontfamily{eurosym}\selectfont e%
    }%
  \EndAccSupp{}%
}

% \usepackage{hyperref}
% \pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\officialeuro\texteuro}

\begin{document}
\euro{} in text mode

$\euro$ in math mode
\end{document}
```

**Remarks:**

- I have modified the first example of [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110979/16967). In case of pdfTeX I would rather use the second example with the embedded font encoding to Unicode mapping.
- A font with `/Euro` as glyph name instead of `/e` would be much better.

AFAIK the best strategy for copy/paste or searching would be:

1. Font with correct glyph names.
2. Font based Unicode mapping.
3. ActualText feature (supported by AR, but not by all PDF viewers).