# Equation with euro symbol

Tags: math-mode, equations

I need to make this equation in LateX but I get some errors when i try to do that.

[image]

Can you help me please??

Comment: Hi and Welcome to TeX.sx. Could you post what code you've tried as a complete, compilable document (even if it yields errors).

Comment: Now im using this code:   
\[{CTrain}_{Tot}= 4h*10\frac { \euro }{ h*pers } *1500pers\]

but i get "e" and not "€"

i had already import the package "eurosym"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'd consider using `siunitx` for this kind of things:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{eurosym}

\DeclareSIUnit{\pers}{pers}
\DeclareSIUnit{\EUR}{\text{\euro}}
\sisetup{
  per-mode = fraction,
  inter-unit-product = \ensuremath{{}\cdot{}},
}

\begin{document}
\[
\mathit{Ctrain}_{\textup{Tot}}=
\SI{4}{h}\cdot \SI{10}{\EUR\per\hour\per\pers}\cdot\SI{1500}{\pers}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: wonderful! thx man! i dont understand every row of your code but thx!

Comment: @dadem `siunitx` is a very powerful and customizable package; give a look at its manual.

Answer (score 3):

Because you do not give more information I can only guess what documentclass you are using and what errors you are fighting. I have added two examples:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern,textcomp}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\begin{document}

${\text{Ctrain}_{\text{Tot}}=4h*10 \frac{\mbox{\euro}}{h*\text{pers}}*1500\text{pers}}$

or

${\text{Ctrain}_{\text{Tot}}=4h*10 \frac{\text{\euro}}{h*\text{pers}}*1500\text{pers}}$

\end{document}
```

You should also use the search function! There is an excellent answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110972/eurosym-seems-to-not-be-working/110973#110973).

Comment: I get answer from @egreg
already try the solution that you linked to me but doesn't work. Solution form egreg was very good!

Answer (score 2):

After read in post, there is variety of ways to get the EUR, texteuro, euro, etc.
Just as an example [Click here](https://www.physicsread.com/latex-euro-symbol/).

But in overleaf, and in my setup with MikTex, and LatexWorshop in visual I get the correcto result as:

`\textup{\euro}`

it comes wit the package:

`\usepackage{eurosym}`

Answer (score -1):

use this in between $ signs :

```
 { CTrain }_{ Tot }\quad =\quad 4h*10\frac { \euro  }{ h*pers } *1500pers
```

To be able to use this code you must first `import required package for euro sign.` You can use any one of following packages:

- `eurosym`
- `eurosans`

**If this is not working on your tex/latex editor use the following link:**

[**http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php**](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php)

Comment: already use it! but i still have the problem with € symbol