# Euro symbol does not show up when defined as a unit for `siunitx`

Tags: siunitx

I am trying to use `\officialeuro` symbol redefined as a unit for `siunitx` package. LaTeX seems to interpret the unit as letter instead of a symbol

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{eurosym}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit{\euro}{\officialeuro}

\begin{document}
    
    $\SI{110}{\kilo\euro}$
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/110972/134144 is also related

Comment: @egreg. Yes, this works for me very well