# R Markdown failed to render PDF and render .tex instead

Tags: xetex, pdftex, rmarkdown

I have been using RMarkdown via R Studio to render PDF for a while but suddenly it failed to render PDF with the following error. Instead of PDF, it render a .tex file which I'm unsure why.

```
"C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS Question-10.2-and-3---RMD --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output Question-10.2-and-3---RMD.tex --lua-filter "C:\Users\hangt\OneDrive\Documents\R\win-library\4.1\rmarkdown\rmarkdown\lua\pagebreak.lua" --lua-filter "C:\Users\hangt\OneDrive\Documents\R\win-library\4.1\rmarkdown\rmarkdown\lua\latex-div.lua" --self-contained --highlight-style tango --pdf-engine pdflatex --variable graphics --variable "geometry:margin=1in" 
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character Â€ (U+0080)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

Try other LaTeX engines instead (e.g., xelatex) if you are using pdflatex. See https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/latex-unicode.html
Error: LaTeX failed to compile Question-10.2-and-3---RMD.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See Question-10.2-and-3---RMD.log for more info.
Execution halted
```

Sorry if the way I describe the issue is vague.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please show the resulting TeX code?

Comment: Sorry for my beginner question. How should I show the resulting TeX code? what is the best way to do it?

Comment: Copy the TeX code and paste it into your question, but delete personal informations!

Comment: It looks like your Rmarkdown file contains the euro symbol, which LaTeX cannot understand. Try loading the `textcomp` package, or see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9868/24974

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to TeX.SE. Your document has a Euro symbol, which can not be compiled by `pdflatex`. There are several possible ways to fix this. Assuming you are writing an `Rmarkdown` document, you can add any one of these to the document header:

1. `\usepackage{eurosym}`
2. `\usepackage{textcomp}`
3. `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{20AC}{\euro}`

Alternatively, you can compile your `.Rmd` file with `xelatex` in `RStudio` by going to `Tools > Global Options > Sweave` and in `Typeset LaTeX into PDF using:` choose `XeLaTeX`.

Here is a MWE that uses the `eurosym` package, which can be compiled with pdflatex.

```
---
title: "TeX.SE"
output: pdf_document
header-includes: 
  - \usepackage{eurosym}
---

The book is 10 \euro.

The book is \euro 10.

The book is \EUR{10}.
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried to change from pdflatex to XeLaTex but the document still couldn't be compiled. I have not tried changing the header yet so I just removed the symbols which were just erroneous symbols. The issue cleared up now. Thanks

Comment: @Grace_radetsk XeLaTeX should allow compiling the file with a U+0080, but most probably will show only  empty space or just a box,  since many fonts have not a glyph for U+00080. However, the U+20AC (€),  that moreover is available in some keyboards,  today will not produce problems even with pdflatex and the default font.  The only disadvantage is that is not the official euro symbol, but you  can force to type  `\euro` instead of U+20AC, as showed in the answer,  i.e., without using that command in the text.